# Align the values on the bar in matplotlib barplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to obtain a bar chart displaying value_counts() for each year.

I use the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.Year.value_counts(sort=False).sort_index().plot(kind='barh')

for index, value in enumerate(df['Year'].value_counts()):
    plt.text(value, index,
         str(value))

plt.show()
```

The chart that I obtain is as follows:

[My bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtW37.png)

While it is correct, the issue is that all values are not aligned above the bars neatly and the alignment of values looks very haphazard. In short, they are not aesthetically pleasing.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this part (perhaps adding some height parameters in the code) so that all the values look neatly aligned on the bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While plotting, you are using `sort_index()` which sorts the bars based on year. But, this uses the sorted values for plotting. When you use the `plt.text()` the numbers are written based on the unsorted values. So, while the text values are in the correct location, the bars are not.

If you provide the data used, can provide the updates. But, I am using the data based on the plot and working backwards here. Note that I am NOT using `value_counts()`, but plotting with just the values in the sample below. See if this helps...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2019,2020,2021,2022], 'Value':[275,237,235,170]})
df.set_index(['Year'], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
print(df)
df.Value.plot(kind='barh')
for index, value in enumerate(df['Value']):
    plt.text(value, index, str(value))
plt.show()
```

**Output**

```
>>  df
      Value
Year       
2019    275
2020    237
2021    235
2022    170
```

[image]